# Do I need to flush my tankless water heater annually?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, tankless

I bought a Rheem tankless water-heater last year, it is RTG-95XLN-1 model. I was told that I need to flush it using vinegar and circular pump at least once a year, to prevent sedimentation. There are tons of YouTube videos advising the same; Home Depot even sells pump and hoses specially dedicated for this purpose. I live in a suburb of Dallas, Texas.

But a veteran plumber told me that I need to do it only 3 to 5 years, as newer model comes with self-cleaning feature. I found his advise very credible, since he has no conflict of interest. And also I checked out Rheem's 2016 generic manual online, but I couldn't see any reference to such annual preventive measure.

Any advise would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It usually depends on the area's water type.  A place with soft water will need it less and a place with very hard water might need it every few months.  Some stores will sell stuff people don't really need, but it makes the store money.  If it has a drain, would wait a few months and see what besides water comes out.

Comment: How hard is your water, and how hard is the water that gets to your water heater (and/or has it been treated in some other way to prevent scale?) In a hard-water area where no treatment is done, things will be very different from a soft-water area or a case where the hard water has been treated before the heater...

Comment: @ Ecnerwal Thanks for your input. I live in Arlington, a suburb of Dallas, TX. Is there any website that tells me the hardness level of any region in the US? Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind about my question about water hardness, I can easily google it. Thanks.

Comment: What's to flush? Where would sediment accumulate? _What do the instructions say?_ (Sounds like it agrees with me.)

Comment: My tank is about 16 years old and has never been flushed. To clean the tank you need to get in there with a brush or something mechanical. Most of what settles in the bottom will stay there even with flushing. I will note on all of my water heaters over the years the bottom (drain) valve is not on the bottom of the tank but up a few inches. My neighbor did it and now has problems with the faucet screens loading with junk.

Comment: @Gil Is your water-heater tankless? Let me know and thank you.

Comment: Tankless water heaters have active components that can be harmed by flushing chemicals through them if not recommended by the manufacturer I would not flush a tankless, the gas fired one I installed in 2000 is still working and that water has a lime buildup issue but it the high heat /cool cycles must keep it from building up, best water heater I ever bought.

Comment: @Ed Beal Thank you for your input. So sorry for getting back late with you.